# imagemagick cropped images to pdf: pdf maintains cropped dimensions

Tags: image, pdf, imagemagick, png

I have a few large pngs. I'm cropping them with convert and then creating a pdf from them.

```
find . -name 'test_*.png' -exec convert -crop 600x1000+400+50 {} {} \; -exec echo {} \;
convert `ls -v test_*.png` test.pdf
```

It all works well enough. The images are cropped fine. The pdf is generally fine. The problem is that each page of the resulting pdf has white padding which matches the pre-cropped image size.

Am I missing a step to reset the image size metadata or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might be better:

```
find . -name 'test_*.png'  -print -exec convert {} -crop 600x1000+400+50 +repage {} \;
convert test_*.png test.pdf
```

I think `-print` amounts more succinctly to `-exec echo {} \;`

The preferred order of ImageMagick commands is:

```
convert input.png ... output.png
```

The `+repage` makes an image forget its previous canvas size.

Comment: Yes, this work perfectly. Thanks for the fix and the other pointers.

Comment: You can maybe avoid writing to disk, if you don't need the files, with `find -name "test*.png" -exec convert {} -crop ... +repage miff:- \; | convert miff:- test.pdf`